Azure SignalR Service: target a specific hub within a Blazor Server app
Within my Blazor server application I want to use Azure SignalR service for communications for a specific Hub.
It seems the AddAzureSignalR() method uses Azure SignalR service for ALL hubs, including Blazor UI updates, e.g:
builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(connStr);

I want to target Azure SignalR for MyHub only:
app.MapHub<MyHub>("/MyHub");

I cannot find an existing answer to this.

May I know if you have got any chance to check my reply? It will be great if you can share more detailed information for us to better investigate this issue. Thanks for your cooperation.

Experiencing the same issue, I have raised a support ticket and confirmed by the Azure SignalR Service team, the partial approach is not supported.
Recommended Design:

[SignalR Server Side] 
Create a separate webapi project for MyHub that connects to Azure Signalr Service.
[SignalR Client Side]  Your blazor project acts as a signalr client to communicate with MyHub in your webapi project.

